# php glob versus scandir

Tags: php, function, unix, scandir

I encounter a peculiarity with the php `glob` function and wonder what the heck is going on.

```
<?php
$paths = glob('../test/*');
echo 'count = ' . count($paths) .'<br/>';
echo 'paths[0] = ' . $paths[0] .'<br/>';
echo 'scandir count = ' . count (scandir ('../test') );
?>
```

The test directory is empty and I get as result

```
count = 1
paths[0] = 
scandir count = 2
```

The `scandir` count of 2 I understand (`.` and `..` are counted too).
But I expected count of `$paths` to be 0, not 1.
And why, if it is 1, does `$paths[0]` have no value?

Comment: From my opinion is strange, I cannot replicate the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What has happened is the "glob" has returned false. This gives the output you've seen.

```
count = 1
paths[0] =
```

Reading one report (http://drupal.org/node/1157100) suggests that `glob()` can fail if you can't read the `../` parent directory, even though you can read `../test`. I presume that `scandir()` doesn't have this restriction, and so it succeeds.

Solution in this case: give yourself permissions to the ../ directory as well.